# Why is my text string line-breaking in a strange way? (HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, ios, css, wkwebview

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwz40x3o/) for this to see the HTML/CSS in detail

I think this is the relevant CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: circle;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

/*
 How to center the bullet vertically with the content:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966278/421797
 (You also have to wrap your li content in a span tag!)
 */
li span {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Ultimately I don't know why an extra line seems to get rendered for a long text string when it should probably have 2-3 line breaks instead.

The JSFiddle above will show the CSS I'm using.  It won't render the problem I'm seeing on iPhone SE:

[image: HTML Rendering Problem]

If anything I would expect:

```
Empfänger
personenbezogener Daten
```

And all the list items have the same margin from the bullet point, and the bullet point should be vertically aligned to its list item content.

```css
/*
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428477/421797
 Makes sure the Browser isn't trying to perform its own magic.
 
 Also,
 You can debug this in the simulator by looking here for how to do that:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771390/421797
 
 */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #46484d;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 27px;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #3d78fe;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p.header {}

p.footer {}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: circle;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}


/*
 How to center the bullet vertically with the content:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966278/421797
 (You also have to wrap your li content in a span tag!)
 */

li span {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 16px;
}


/*
 How to choose different images depending on screen properties
 https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/
 */

ul.bullets {
  list-style-image: -webkit-image-set( url("ovalCopy.png") 1x, url("ovalCopy@2x.png") 2x, url("ovalCopy@3x.png") 3x);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
<div id="content">
  <p class="header">
    Blahblahblah, I redacted this for our product in test.
  </p>
  <ul class="bullets">
    <li><span>Datenkategorien</span></li>
    <li><span>Zwecke der Datenverarbeitung</span></li>
    <li><span>Empfänger personenbezogener Daten</span></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="footer">
    Etwas unklar? <a href="getInTouch">Schreib uns.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow also has a snippet editor `[<>]`

Comment: NOTE:  I'm also open to other ways to achieve the same goal, such as div classes for list items with floating image bullets.  We're using HTML as a rendering method, not because it needs to be semantically awesome.

Comment: I do not recommend any vertically alignment of the bullet points other then top. This is beyond user expectations. If you happen to have a long `<li>` content, the user can't tell, where the new `li` begins and the previous `li` ends as it looks just like an ordinary paragraph at the first glance. Some users might even think that the list has ended altogether.

Comment: It's really not my decision how something is supposed to look visually.  This is why we have designers.  In the context of what our app is doing, a vertically-aligned bullet point makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom `:before` and `display:table-cell`, check below

```css
/*
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428477/421797
 Makes sure the Browser isn't trying to perform its own magic.
 
 Also,
 You can debug this in the simulator by looking here for how to do that:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771390/421797
 
 */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #46484d;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 27px;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #3d78fe;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p.header {}

p.footer {}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: circle;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  display:table;
  position:relative;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;  
  top:calc(50% - 3px);  
  margin: 0px 0 0 -12px;    
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  border-radius:100%;
}


/*
 How to center the bullet vertically with the content:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966278/421797
 (You also have to wrap your li content in a span tag!)
 */

li span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 16px;
}


/*
 How to choose different images depending on screen properties
 https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/
 */

ul.bullets {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
<div id="content">
  <p class="header">
    Blahblahblah, I redacted this for our product in test.
  </p>
  <ul class="bullets">
    <li><span>Datenkategorien</span></li>
    <li><span>Zwecke der Datenverarbeitung</span></li>
    <li><span>Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener Daten</span></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="footer">
    Etwas unklar? <a href="getInTouch">Schreib uns.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Second Example with image

```css
/*
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428477/421797
 Makes sure the Browser isn't trying to perform its own magic.
 
 Also,
 You can debug this in the simulator by looking here for how to do that:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771390/421797
 
 */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #46484d;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 27px;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #3d78fe;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p.header {}

p.footer {}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: circle;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  display:table;
  position:relative;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;  
  top:calc(50% - 3px);  
  margin: 0px 0 0 -12px;    
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent url('http://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/6x6.png?css=%7B%22border-radius%22%3A%2215px%22%7D') no-repeat;
}


/*
 How to center the bullet vertically with the content:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966278/421797
 (You also have to wrap your li content in a span tag!)
 */

li span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 16px;
}


/*
 How to choose different images depending on screen properties
 https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/
 */

ul.bullets {
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;" />
<div id="content">
  <p class="header">
    Blahblahblah, I redacted this for our product in test.
  </p>
  <ul class="bullets">
    <li><span>Datenkategorien</span></li>
    <li><span>Zwecke der Datenverarbeitung</span></li>
    <li><span>Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener DatenEmpfänger personenbezogener Daten</span></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="footer">
    Etwas unklar? <a href="getInTouch">Schreib uns.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool!  It's almost there. in that the lines are breaking well, and the layout is as I would hope.  However, I see you're rendering bullets in CSS.  I'd like to be able to use our image, but at the end of the day, I might be able to work with this.

Comment: @horseshoe7 Instead of css we can use image also

Comment: sweet!  Thanks for the update.  I'll look at it shortly, and I think this will be what I mark as the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of all of these

```
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
li span {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
```

and set

```
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```css
ul {
  /* list-style-position: inside; */
  list-style-type: circle;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

/*
 How to center the bullet vertically with the content:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966278/421797
 (You also have to wrap your li content in a span tag!)
 */

li span {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* padding-left: 16px; */
}

/*
 How to choose different images depending on screen properties
 https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/
 */

ul.bullets {
  list-style-image: -webkit-image-set( url("ovalCopy.png") 1x, url("ovalCopy@2x.png") 2x, url("ovalCopy@3x.png") 3x);
}






/*
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428477/421797
 Makes sure the Browser isn't trying to perform its own magic.
 
 Also,
 You can debug this in the simulator by looking here for how to do that:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771390/421797
 
 */

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #46484d;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 27px;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p class="header">
    Blahblahblah, I redacted this for our product in test.
  </p>
  <ul class="bullets">
    <li><span>Datenkategorien</span></li>
    <li><span>Zwecke der Datenverarbeitung</span></li>
    <li><span>Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten Empfänger personenbezogener Daten</span></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="footer">
    Etwas unklar? <a href="getInTouch">Schreib uns.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

You might think of replacing

```
li span {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

with

```
li span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

as the former looks a little bit hacky and code-smelly

Comment: Awesome dude! the simple you write, the better you have.

Answer (score 0):

as i checked, you need to remove:

```
ul li {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    remove this > word-break: normal;
    and this > word-wrap: normal;
}
```

and remove all of this:

```
remove all this > li span {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

Image :

[image]

Save fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u3shocnv/

Simply try this :

```
ul.bullets {
    list-style: none !important;
}

ul li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul li::before {
    content: '•';
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}

ul li span {
}
```

Screenshot :

[image]

(EDIT:  This produced the following result on the device:)

[image: Result]

Comment: except I want the bullet aligned to the middle of the list item content, and any second line should be indented the same as the first.

Comment: I've edited the code and saved the fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/e9j8Lybp/1/

Comment: That's almost there!  What's missing now are the bullet images we are using, and the bullet point is no longer vertically aligned to the centre of the content.

Comment: Why to use bullet images while you can fontawesome or any other icon font library? its better for your server load?

Comment: a) I'm not the designer
b) There is no server load.  The images are in the app bundle.

Comment: You can use @yunzen solution as described in his answer